# Getting one day less when trying to validate into full calendar

Tags: jquery, datetime, fullcalendar

I´m implementing fullCalendar but I have a problem when I try to validate:

I cant post an event who `postdate < currentdate` so I have something like

```
var date = new Date();
var currentDay= moment().startOf('day');

function isGreaterThanToday(date) {
    return date < currentDate? false : true;
}

function updateAssignedEvent(event, delta, revertFunc) {

    if (!isGreaterThanToday(event.start)) {
         alert("You cant introduce an event before today.");
         revertFunc();
         return;
    }
```

But my `date` is always one day less, so If I try to post today I get alert but I want to post the actual day. What can I do there? why I´m getting one day less? Regards

Comment: what is "currentDate"? It appears to be undefined. Anyway, It's generally unwise to compare dates like this anyway. Since you've got momentJS available, use moment's query functions to get reliable results. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/

Answer (score 0):

Use moment [isAfter](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/) function.

> If nothing is passed to moment#isAfter, it will default to the current time.

This is example to check if event start is before current time.

```
function updateAssignedEvent(event, delta, revertFunc) {    
        if (moment(event.start).isAfter()) {
            alert("You cant introduce an event before today.");
            revertFunc();
            return;
        }
    }
```